# Could there been some "Seer" Blood in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, divination

> The heat was overpowering and his nostrils were stinging with the
>   perfumed smoke wafting from the fire beside them. He thought of what Ron
>   had just said, and decided to pretend.
>
> "Er --" said Harry, "a dark shape... um..."
>
> "What does it resemble?" whispered Professor Trelawney. "Think, now..."
>
> Harry cast his mind around and it landed on Buckbeak.
>
> "A hippogriff," he said firmly.
>
> "Indeed!" whispered Professor Trelawney, scribbling keenly on the
>   parchment perched upon her knees. "My boy, you may well be seeing the
>   outcome of poor Hagrid's trouble with the Ministry of Magic! Look
>   closer... Does the hippogriff appear to... have its head?"
>
> "Yes," said Harry firmly.
>
> "Are you sure?" Professor Trelawney urged him. "Are you quite sure,
>   dear? You don't see it writhing on the ground, perhaps, and a shadowy
>   figure raising an axe behind it?"
>
> "No!" said Harry, starting to feel slightly sick.
>
> "No blood? No weeping Hagrid?"
>
> "No!" said Harry again, wanting more than ever to leave the room and the
>   heat. "It looks fine, it's - - flying away..."

I know some may say that because he didn't want Buckbeak to be killed, or he was pretending. But for pretending, was it a coincidence that his mind landed on Buckbeak. Was it a coincidence that he told her that it was flying away(knowing that he may not have been able to concentrate on what he was saying because the uncomfortable surroundings)? Or was it some seer thingy coming into play that made Harry predict the future?

Comment: Don't forget how Trelawney went on both occasions she was an actual Seer (rather than just a silly old bat who believed her own nonsense about tea leaves and crystal orbs), she went into a trance and didn't remember ever having made any predictions—there's no sign of Harry ever having done that, unless perhaps Ginny persuaded him to do LSD at some point…

Comment: The books did show divination worked around him, kinda... I think the teacups were also fairly accurate (unexpected windfall, trials and suffering, great happiness), and in GoF when 'making up' predictions based on star charts two of his come true (being burned, because skrewts, and being betrayed by Ron). Of course, they're kind of generic, and the author can meddle, but it might work.  I also heard an unproven theory that a touch of the sight explains why his visions were third person (swooping down with an owl) instead of only looking through Voldie's eyes, but take with a grain of salt.

Comment: The confirmation bias is strong here...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ginny convincing Harry to do LSD, that would be an interesting story! Harry Potter and the Acid Trip, look, we already have a title for it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, it's possible

The Pottermore article about [Sybill Trelawney](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/sybill-trelawney) shows that seer blood can get diluted though the generations until it is almost gone:

> Sybill is the great-great granddaughter of a genuine Seer, Cassandra Trelawney. **Cassandra's gift has been much diluted over ensuing generations**, although Sybill has inherited more than she knows.

Also, as Sirius says, all Wizards are related:

> “You’re related  to  the Malfoys!”
>   “**The pure-blood families are all interrelated**,” said Sirius. “If you’re only going to let your sons and daughters marry purebloods your choice is very limited, there are hardly any of us left.
>   (OotP6)

As Megha points out, the fact that a lot of divination works around him throughout the books (see [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110940/did-harrys-tea-leaf-prophecy-come-true)), and that he sees and visions in third person may be indication that he does have seer blood.

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that although it's perfectly possible that Harry has some Seer blood [no, auto-correct, I don't mean _deer blood_] in him, there is no evidence that he ever exhibits any kind of Seer abilities, including the scene quoted in this question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah, autocorrect... the enemy of fandom-specific words... Well, Harry's father was an Animagus who could turn into a stag, so he might've had some deer blood, too! :P

Comment: @Bellatrix And Lily’s Patronus was a doe, so very likely!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Harry's Patronus was also a stag, so there's our proof! :)

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt Harry had any ability to predict the future. As we know, throughout the 3rd, 4th and 5th books, Harry and Ron constantly fake their Divination homework, especially when it is to do with predicting events. Also, in his fifth year O.W.L's, Harry does quite poorly in Divination, getting a P (Poor) grade.

Like you mentioned, the reason Harry suggested Buckbeak would still have his head is because he desperately wanted the hipogriff to survive.

Comment: Marks doesn't qualify intelligence, as there are countless examples, I know he might have been not. He might just have some seer blood in it because as mentioned in ibid's answer and Megha's comment, he might be unintentionally making correct predictions... You never would have known what is possible. I just wanted to know if Rowling ever canonned the fact that he was somewhere related to any seer...